# Регулярное выражение для поиска предложения состоящее только из одного слова

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такие предложения:
1)Ужас
2)Прекрасный обзор
3)Кстати говоря, именно в сталкере самая продвинутая живность в играх...

Мне нужно выделить только первое предложение, которое состоит всего из одного слова с помощью регулярных выражений. Как это сделать?

Пробовал так:

```
\w+{1}
```

Но само собой ошибка.

Разве что вот так, но тут выделяются предложения, которые оканчиваются на пробел.:

```
\w+\s$
```

Comment: чем `^\S+$` или `^\w+$` не подходят?

Comment: `^[^ ]+$` тоже может подойти.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение `\w+{1}` неверно, так как квантификатор `{1}` не может стоять сразу после квантификатора `+`. Вообще, квантификатор `{1}` в принципе не должен использоваться, так как любой шаблон тестируется на соответствие один раз по умолчанию.

Решения:

- `^\S+$` - от начала до конца в строке могут быть только символы, отличные от пробельных
- `^\w+$` - от начала до конца в строке могут быть только буквы, цифры или знаки подчёркивания (в зависимости от библиотеки регулярных выражений, также могут быть некоторые диакритические знаки)
- `^[^ ]+$` - от начала до конца в строке могут быть только символы, отличные от пробела.

Если после `^` и перед `$` добавить `\s*`, будут разрешены 0 и более пробельных символов в начале и конце строки.